# How render Date Format on Freemarker from Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I try to work with date fields in `Freemarker`.

Here is my controller methods for creating Account objects:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/accounts/add")
    public String showAddAccount(Model model) {
        Account account = new Account();
        model.addAttribute("add", true);
        model.addAttribute("account", account);

        return "account-edit";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/accounts/add")
    public String addAccount(
            Model model,
            @ModelAttribute("account") Account account
    ) {
        try {
            Account newAccount = accountService.save(account);
            return "redirect:/accounts/" + newAccount.getId();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String errorMessage = e.getMessage();
            logger.error(errorMessage);
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);

            model.addAttribute("add", true);
            return "account-edit";
        }
    }
```

It is part of my Freemarker template, where I am formatting date:

```
        <#if account.createdOn??>
            <tr>
                <td>Created On</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>${(account.createdOn).format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Updated On</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>${(account.updatedOn).format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}</td>
            </tr>
        </#if>
```

I have added dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>no.api.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker-java8</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I found this dependency to use Data/Time in Java 8 in template.
After I added config class for freemarker:

```
@Configuration
public class FreemarkerConfig implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof FreeMarkerConfigurer) {
            FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = (FreeMarkerConfigurer) bean;
            configurer.getConfiguration().setObjectWrapper(new Java8ObjectWrapper(freemarker.template.Configuration.getVersion()));
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

I am receiving an error "Column 'created_on' cannot be null" and:

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Comment: You named your input `service`. It must be named `serviceName`, since that's the name of the property in Account.

Comment: @JBNizet yeah, i didnt know that its important :( parametr name = my field of entity?

now i have same error with dates. Additionally - if i comment annotations on date fields -     @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false), i am getting other error - https://pastebin.com/WqpLKF1Q

Comment: deleted that .format methods from html files and added @DateTimeFormat to entity fields - didnt help

Comment: exactly before that error i have:
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'created_on' cannot be null

Comment: @AndrewKorzhov According to the error, when you saving `account` object somehow `created_on` going null to the database. Any I think you put validation on your domain class.